# Facebook's image proxy issue when using graph (feed) api

Tags: php, facebook, graph

Im trying to submit an image to the feed, using the example like http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/feed but the image has parameters, like this one:

http://www.primafiat.com.br/img-cache/get-image.php?i=1982110/249.png

How to make it work? Facebook image proxy is not recognizing the image, I believe it is trailing the part after the '?'.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried urlencoding it?

Comment: tried http://www.primafiat.com.br/img-cache/get-image.php%3Fi=1982110%2F249.png
and 
http://www.primafiat.com.br/img-cache/get-image.php?i=1982110%2F249.png

both didn't worked.
tried also: 
'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.primafiat.com.br%2Fimg-cache%2Fget-image.php%3Fi%3D1982110%2F249.png'
'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.primafiat.com.br%2Fimg-cache%2Fget-image.php%3Fi%3D1982110%2F249.png'
'http://www.primafiat.com.br/img-cache/get-image.php%3Fi%3D1982110%2F249.png'
'http://www.primafiat.com.br/img-cache/get-image.php%3Fi=1982110%2F249.png'

Comment: "best" result with:
'http://www.primafiat.com.br/img-cache/get-image.php?i=1982110/249.png'
when it removes anything after the '?'

Comment: See my answer, it should be: http://www.primafiat.com.br/img-cache/get-image.php?i=1982110%2F249.png

Comment: the problem is the '?' before the 'i'...

Answer (score 0):

The parameters need encoding, use this:

[http://www.primafiat.com.br/img-cache/get-image.php?i=1982110%2F249.png](http://www.primafiat.com.br/img-cache/get-image.php?i=1982110/249.png)

Comment: tried and it didn't worked... the problem is the question mark